# Error when adding columns with default values to dataframe with zero rows

Tags: r, dataframe

**Why does this work**,

```
# add ONE column to dataframe with zero rows

x <- data.frame(a=character(0))
x["b"] <- character(0)
```

**while this does not?**

```
# add SEVERAL columns to dataframe with zero rows

x <- data.frame(a=character(0))
x[c("b", "c")] <- character(0)

error in value[[jvseq[[jjj]]]] : index out of limits  [... freely translated]
```

Note, that this is perfectly okay, if we have non-zero rows.

```
x <- data.frame(a=1)
x["b"] <- NA

x <- data.frame(a=1)
x[c("b", "c")] <- NA
```

**And what would be a simple alternative to add multiple columns to zero row dataframes?**

Comment: `cbind(x, b=character(0), c=character(0))`.

Comment: `cbind(x,as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 42, nrow = 0)))` for many columns.

Comment: unfortunately, this does not help me, as I do not know in advance, what the columns names will be. Anyway, I could, of course, loop: `for (m in c("a", "b")) x[[m]] <- character(0)`

Comment: @StanislavIvanov The columns are not named as given in the vector in your solution.

Comment: I can't imagine a good reason why you would need this. You should never need to deal with zero-row data.frames.

Comment: @MarkHeckmann You can call just `names(x) <- c ("a","b","c")` after.

Comment: @Roland. I stumbled across this when converting JSON -> R. I cannot control the JSON structures I receive and the R code all works fine except for this seldom case.

Comment: Anyway, the question remains if this is an inconsistency in df usage  that is meant to be or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `help("[.data.frame")`:

> Data frames can be indexed in several modes. When [ and [[ are used
>   with a single vector index (x[i] or x[[i]]), they index the data frame
>   as if it were a list.

From `help("[")`:

> **Recursive (list-like) objects**
>
> Indexing by [ is similar to atomic vectors and selects a list of the specified element(s).

Thus, you need to do pass a list (or data.frame):

```
x <- data.frame(a=character(0))
x[c("b", "c")] <- list(character(0), character(0))
str(x)
#'data.frame':  0 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ a: Factor w/ 0 levels: 
# $ b: chr 
# $ c: chr
```